# Mixed content error vs warning

Tags: google-chrome, mixed-content

What determines whether an insecure resource is blocked or loaded anyway with a warning?

Screenshot from Chrome 53:
[image: Screenshot from Chrome 53]

Created by:

```
(function(){var d=document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');for(var i=0,l=d.length;i<l;i++){d[i].setAttribute('src','http://placekitten.com/'+d[i].width+'/'+d[i].height)};}())
```

Comment: Weird, it looks like Chrome lets the first one go through but block the rest. It should probably block all of them.

Comment: @this.lau_ That's not it. See new screenshot.

Comment: Is there any way to replicate this issue? How are the placekitten images inserted in the Wikipedia main page? As a fix they could be inserted with a protocol relative URL like "//placekiten.com/51/30" but that still wouldn't explain why Chrome is not consistent with the warnings and errors.

Comment: I added the code, run it in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blocked images are those where the `img` has a [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) specified.

[image: Screenshot of F12 Developer tools console in Chrome showing srcset]

Chrome and Firefox actively block mixed content when an `img` has a `srcset`. The `src` here is an http resource while the `srcset` uses https.

[Chromium Issue 402792 - Mixed content: `<img>` with empty srcset attribute should be active content](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390158)

[Mozilla Bug 1055750 - (srcset-mixed-content) Block mixed content `<img srcset>` and `<picture>`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1055750)